# do not create mywebsitefolder in the virtual directory after creating new web application at sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

pls give me any suggestion ...

i create new web application at sharepoint 2007 ...

and i run STSADM.EXE -o createsite to get empty site collection ...  and operation completed successfully ...

but do not create my website folder 8082 in virtual directory .. and also i cannot see my site in the iis ..

i do not run iisreset because yesterday .. we was at the production environment ...

at my office, i can see my website folder after create new web application withouting doing iisreset ...

pls give me any suggestion ...

thanks a lot,

MTH83

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Site Collections and Web Sites are not created under IIS. They are defined within the content database.

From more information see [An Overview of the SharePoint Platform for ASP.NET Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649459.aspx):

> Sites are similar in concept to virtual directories in ASP.NET, although they are not equivalent. A site contains more functionality and is not actually a virtual directory. For example, in SharePoint, pages for a site are often rendered by merging file-based definitions, page templates, and content from the content database. This type of page is termed a site page or content page. The template can either be defined in a file or stored on the content database.